# Post-Migration Logging Issue in Python 3 GAE Application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

We have recently migrated our application from Python 2 to Python 3 on Google App Engine and are encountering a recurring issue related to logging. Despite the application's functionality appearing unaffected, our error console consistently reports problems with submitting logs. This issue seems to be happening in the background but it is causing concerns regarding the reliability and integrity of our logging process, which is critical to us for analytics and security.

Error Details:

The error we are seeing is as follows:

"Failed to submit 10 logs"

And the traceback includes:

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 79, in error_remapped_callable return callable_(*args, **kwargs)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1160, in **call**
return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)

(See Image for more extensive trace)

FYI: We now have over 4,500+ occurrences of the issue in less than 4 days!!!

Steps to reproduce: Unknown

Other information (workarounds we have tried, documentation consulted, etc.):

1. Try to identify if these errors occur when hitting particular endpoint - could not identify as errors keep happening all around, every minute and are not associated with any request log
2. Use latest cloud SDK CLI version while deploying (459.0.0)
3. Use the gcloud beta command
4. There is a Github thread for a similar error which says the issue got fixed back in 2017, however other people have faced this issue again as mentioned in comments
   https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/3407

We are seeking assistance in diagnosing and resolving this issue.

Is there are any known issues with logging in GAE applications post Python 3 migration?

Additional Information:

Environment: Google App Engine
Runtime: Python 3.11
appengine-python-standard>=0.2.3
google-cloud-logging==3.8.0

Thank you for your assistance.
Regards

Edit 1:

[These errors do not have a trace id to them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyivS.png)

[Full error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbcZh.png)

[Full error logs continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM1yY.png)

Comment: Move your comments to the question and delete them. Do not use comments for additional data. Since one of your problems is very large log entries, review why your app is doing that and reduce their size. Without details on what is failing, we can only guess. Edit your question once you have details we can review.

Comment: Sure John, deleted old comments and will post them as a separate question since it is un-related to above question. Regarding the original question, could please help clarify what else information I can share, happy to do that.

Comment: FYI John: We now have more that 20,000 errors reported. We have been maintaining a large application on GCP for many years. We know when an issue is from the app and when it is in library. Just like the threading exception thrown by cloud logging - this is also an issue in your library and not our app as we have not changed any code or logging statements. (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-dashboard/issues/3197)

Let me know your email and what details I can send to you.

Comment: If you are convinced that this is a Google bug (and I am not), create an issue on Google's Issue Tracker. See this [guide](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui). Suggestion: in your post, you included a couple of log entries. Those are part of a large set called a Stack Trace. We would need to see the entire Stack Trace, which might be 10 to 20 log entries. If you understand Python, you can determine the start and end of one Stack Trace. A fragment or two is not useful.

Comment: Google sometimes has bugs like all products. However, for a product like App Engine used by millions, you would typically already find bug reports for your issue. Search the Issue Tracker to see if your problem has been previously reported and if it already has a solution. At this point, I don't know what your problem is as there is not enough details to analyze.

Comment: I have opened the ticket on issue tracker already, before asking on StackOverflow: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319693075

However, as usual they are not interested in replying. As mentioned in my point 1 - these logs do not have any trace id associated so we cannot link it to any set of logs from a request (Updated question above to show this). 

Albeit, I am ready to share more detailed logs (updated the question) if you think I am missing something. So would be great if you can mention any other details you require.

Comment: I find it amusing that if someone's issue is not reported / faced by anyone else then the GCP support and community will not help them and simply say "Check out issue tracker and wait to see if anyone else reports it, if no one reports we will just say that issue tracker is for public issues - we will not update our library to print detail error message - we will not mention the trace id which caused the issue - so you are on your own and we don't care."

Comment: Your code is crashing. That is not a Google problem. Review the stack traces and fix each problem. Did you update each library that your application requires to Python 3?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community of volunteers. You are asking for free help. That means you cannot demand or expect anything. I recommend you open an official Google Cloud support ticket.

Comment: Not sure if my code is crashing because all requests seem to be working. Just that in the background when logs are submitted - that is failing. As you may have noticed the stack trace I shared - nothing related to my app is printed - any file, line number, trace id, exception / error reason - hence I am not sure what to review in the stack trace. 

Libraries are as follows:
Flask>=2.0.0

appengine-python-standard>=0.2.3

Jinja2~=3.1.2 

gunicorn==21.2.0 

google-cloud-logging==3.8.0

Comment: Yes I am definitely asking for free help. Just that all the issues I have been facing on GCP and their unhelpful response on tickets - what I said above was all directed to them, please ignore (unless you are also officially part of GCP - if you are not then sorry about the heat!). 

I do appreciate at least someone commenting. 

Could you please share how to open a official cloud support ticket? (Please don't share the link which takes me to some sort of a package that I need pay to be able to have access to open such a ticket)

Comment: Google Cloud Support is paid. For free support, use StackOverflow or Google Issue Tracker. Tips: your post does not have the details to help you. Your problem is most likely easy to solve. Your code is crashing so we need to see the code and the complete stack trace of the error. Without those details, we can only guess. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, edit your post with new details. Do not use comments to improve your question.

Comment: Please do not take this the wrong way. Knowing how to debug programming problems is a skill. You must develop that skill yourself. Spend time on Stackoverflow reading other questions and answers. The first step is to clearly define the error. Then isolate the code that causes the error. Create repeatable tests. Once that is done, you can analyze the code to find the problem. Stack traces show the path the code executed. Just because a trace shows a library does not mean the library is the problem and seldom does.

Comment: Thank you for the tips John. I understand that above details are not enough for someone to debug the issue. The primary issue I am facing is to link the error stack trace to any request log. Since I am unable to do so - it is extremely hard to zero down on a part of my code that maybe causing this, as I have to check all request logs and compare all app logs to see no log is missing. So far I see all app logs are logged - so I am unable to find the request with missing logs (my assumption here is that error says failed to submit 10 logs so some logs should probably be missing)

Comment: I am not talking about missing logs. Pick any log entry with a Python error. Collect the stack trace from the logs and then debug that error. One error at a time.